# updating the nested arrays in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I know that We can update only 1 level down. But can someone tell me, one level down it means that I can update only _id, name, users, lists? or list/cards ???

I know that I can use dot notation like lists.1.list, but can I make dot notation with use variable req.body.number ? for example lists.reqbody.number.lists ? I tried did not work, maybe I do something wrong. Can someone help me?

```
    {
"_id" : ObjectId("59e096a7622a3825ac24f343"),
"name" : "1",
"users" : [ 
    ObjectId("59cd114cea98d9326ca1c421")
],
"lists" : [ 
    {
        "list" : "1",
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "2",
                "Author" : [ 
                    "59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d", 
                    "59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d", 
                    "59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22e"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "3",
                "Author" : []
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "list" : "fea",
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "card",
                "Author" : []
            }
        ]
    }
],
"__v" : 0 }
```

Comment: You can update a `list`or set `lists` as a whole new array. Also you can `set` any field of a `list` inside `lists` array with positional `$` operator. But only one `list` can be updated not multiple. And for `cards`, you can `set` a new array for it too. What you cannot do is that, updating a single `card` element of `cards` or updating(setting) a field of a single card.

Comment: Ok, tell me that i understand it good in relations with arrays "cards", If I have variable for example var cardsObj. And in this variable I have { "name" : "3", "Author" : [ "dada"]  }. with idBoard and index which cards, so I can do query which will update me only selected index? In this case index 1 cards in lists ? (with using cardsObj.indexCards) ??

Comment: I couldn't follow with idBoard. What is it? If you know exact index of each element in subarrays, you can ofcourse update. For example, if you want to update second author of card name 2 and list 1; `lists.0.cards.0.Authors.1`

Comment: Yes ok, but how can I do that if i have index authors in variable var indexAuthor = 2; I cant make lists.0.cards.0.Authors.indexAuthor because it did not work. Can u please tell me how to make it with variable which have in itself indexAuthor ???

Comment: @barbakini can you try answer me???

Comment: It should work. See [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-elements-in-arrays)

Comment: Yes but in $set they did not use variable with index, maybe I can't use variable in $set?     { $set:
      {
        lists.0.cards.0.Authors.req.body.indexAuthor : "rain gear",
      }
   }
It didnt work